# How to simulate LTE in Veins(Framework, along with SUMO and Omnet++), along with Bluetooth and DSRC?

Tags: simulation, network-protocols, omnet++, veins, sumo

I want to simulate a scenario on veins, where in the message is first sent to device on car via bluetooth, and then shared using LTE. But Veins itself is very complicated to understand, and hence, I am not able to proceed

I have already worked out the Scenario example, and tried to make some changes, but unable to understand how to proceed further. Can I get some help what other tools/frameworks should I use, and how shall I proceed. I am currently using Omnet++ 5.3 and Sumo-0.32.0, and Veins-4.7 .

The Sumo part is quite clear, and already implemented, I need help regarding the Omnet++ part.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Are you looking for an overview of the OMNeT++ ecosystem (which frameworks are available, which are compatible, ...?), for an installation guide, or for a tutorial on one of the frameworks?

Comment: No, I am familiar with basics of omnet++. I can simulate basic DSRC protocol using veins. I want to add bluetooth support, so that if a RSU is not present, the emergency message can be sent to device using bluetooth(bluetooth device is present in the car), and then broadcast using LTE. I want some help regarding how it can be done, and what files do I need to change in veins?? I have also implemented bluetooth as its own module(standalone), but cannot link both...

Comment: The OMNeT++ user's manual has a section on 9.2.12 Projects with Multiple Source Trees - see https://www.omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:build-sim-progs:projects-with-multiple-source-trees